# MVC4 - How to rearrange generated fields created by Scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have a .cshtml file created by MVC4 scaffolding that looks something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>BicycleSellerListing</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BicycleManfacturer)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ManufacturerList")
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BicycleType)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("TypeList")
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ListingPrice)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ListingPrice)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ListingPrice)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

Instead of the labels and columns being generated in a single vertical column, I would like to rearrange this so that I have labels in one column and editor fields in a second column (more of a traditional data entry form). I am very new to MVC 4 and HTML5 and don't really know how to go about doing this. If someone could help me rearrange this .cshtml code to accomplish this, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `float:left` and `:before`

http://jsfiddle.net/fdLca/

```
.editor-label {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
}

.editor-label:before {
    clear:left;
}

.editor-field {
    float:left;
    width:80%;
}
```

To get around using :before if you needed to support [older IE](http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/) (< 9) then you can add an element purely being used to clear in between each field and label.

http://jsfiddle.net/fdLca/1/

HTML

```
<div class="editor-label">
    label1
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("ManufacturerList")
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS

```
.clear {
    clear:left;
}
```